# PrimeFaces LazyDataModel resolves rows incorrectly after live scroll?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, el

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces 5.3 (with JSF 2.2) to implement a data table that contains items, and each item has a list of command buttons to perform server side actions. I use primefaces LazyDataModel because I have huge datasets and cannot afford to load all the items when the view loads. But after livescrolling happens, rows do not behave as expected.

I have setup a small project to illustrate my issue. (full sources at the end of the post)

[image: Screenshot]

### The issue

When I press A0, "Executed A0" must be printed on the console (and so on).

Everything works fine for the first data set. Here's what happens when I press the first three buttons:

```
Fetching starting at 0       //expected result  
Executed A0                  //A0
Executed A1                  //A1
Executed A2                  //A2
```

But when I scroll, and 3 other items are loaded, the first three rows do not work correctly.

[image: After scrolling]

Here's what happens when I press all the buttons in order:

```
Fetching starting at 3    //expected result
Executed A3               //A0
Executed A4               //A1
Executed A5               //A2
Executed A3               //A3
Executed A4               //A4
Executed A5               //A5
```

The first three buttons execute the actions of the last three ones :(

### A server-side issue

It is not a client-side issue, I have monitored the requests sent.

When I press A0, the request contains the following POST parameters:

```
j_idt8:resultsTable:0:j_idt12:0:j_idt13=j_idt8:resultsTable:0:j_idt12:0:j_idt13
javax.faces.source=j_idt8:resultsTable:0:j_idt12:0:j_idt13
```

And when I press A3:

```
j_idt8:resultsTable:3:j_idt12:0:j_idt13=j_idt8:resultsTable:3:j_idt12:0:j_idt13
javax.faces.source=j_idt8:resultsTable:3:j_idt12:0:j_idt13
```

The correct row is referenced after resultsTable:

### Debug mode

I also messed with the debug mode. When I press A1, the UIData#brodacast(FacesEvent) is called with an event that contains a field rowIndex=1. So it works fine at this point.

Then, I don't really understand what happens. But at the end of the process, the target method is executed on the wrong instance...

### Source code

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<ItemAction> actions;
    public Item(int id, String name, List<ItemAction> actions) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.actions = actions;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<ItemAction> getActions() {
        return actions;
    }
}
```

ItemAction.java

```
public class ItemAction {
    private String label;
    public ItemAction(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("Executed " + label);
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

TheService.java

```
public class TheService {
    private static final int ITEMS_COUNT = 8;
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return ITEMS_COUNT;
    }
    public List<Item> retrieveItems(int startIndex, int pageSize){
        List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>(pageSize);
        int endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
        if(endIndex > ITEMS_COUNT){
            endIndex = ITEMS_COUNT;
        }
        for(int index=startIndex; index<endIndex; index++){
            result.add(generateItem(index));
        }
        return result;
    }
    private Item generateItem(int id){
        List<ItemAction> actions = new ArrayList<>(2);
        actions.add(new ItemAction("A" + id));
        actions.add(new ItemAction("B" + id));
        return new Item(id, "Item " + id, actions);
    }
}
```

DatatableLazyModel.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DatatableLazyModel extends LazyDataModel<Item>{
    private TheService service;
    private List<Item> allResults;
    public DatatableLazyModel() {
        this.service = new TheService();
        this.allResults = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return service.getItemsCount();
    }
    @Override
    public List<Item> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
            Map<String, Object> filters) {
        System.out.println("Fetching starting at " + first);
        List<Item> pageResults = service.retrieveItems(first, pageSize);
        allResults.addAll(pageResults);
        return pageResults;
    }
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="template/ui.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h3>Datatablelazy load</h3>

        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="resultsTable" var="item"
                value="#{datatableLazyModel}" liveScroll="true" scrollRows="3"
                scrollHeight="100" scrollable="true" lazy="true">

                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Actions">
                    <ui:repeat var="action" value="#{item.actions}">
                        <p:commandButton action="#{action.execute()}" value="#{action.label}">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>5.3</version>  
    </dependency>
```

### Questions

I have tried this with more items loaded. Each time, only methods on the last loaded set are executed. Even from old components.

So basically, the question is : **"How can I make all the buttons work as expected?"**

Why do methods do not get executed on the correct instance? How is the target instance resolved?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml the xhtml calls a viewScoped bean value="#{dtScrollView.cars6}" which in turn declares  ManagedProperty("org.primefaces.showcase.service.CarService@da2d11")
  private CarService service; where CarService is declared as ManagedBean(name = "carService")
ApplicationScoped. I gently ask you to do a similar approach rather than value="#{datatableLazyModel}".  The LazyDatamodels in my application are not annotated with ManagedBean or scope at all. They just reside in MB as variables and are initialized on PostConstruct.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, my datasets are huge and I can't load everything at once, this is why I am using the LazyDataModel. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: I neither asked you to load everything at once nor did i ask you to remove the LazyDataModel.  A properly written load method will take care of it. I think we are talking two different languages. Hope somebody else answers you. Good luck. Bye

Comment: You told me to do the same approach as value="#{dtScrollView.cars6}" . Here the value is a List and not a LazyDataModel. How can I use this approach and a lazy data model?

Comment: i meant cars6 is initialized as private DatatableLazyModel<Item> cars6 . Initialize cars6 in PostConstruct of ViewScoped MB. In the load method of your LazyDataModel add something along the lines of query.setFirstResult(first);query.setMaxResults(pageSize);  currentObjectList = query.getResultList();  return currentObjectList; Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the LazyDataModel implementation that is meant to be used with pages and not live scroll, especially this snippet :

```
if(rowIndex == -1 || pageSize == 0)
        this.rowIndex = -1;
    else
        this.rowIndex = (rowIndex % pageSize);
```

I subclassed LazyDataModel with my own implementation to solve the problem.

**LiveScrollLazyDataModel.java**

```
public abstract class LiveScrollLazyModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<T> {

    private int rowIndex;

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        int oldIndex = getRowIndex();

        if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0){
            super.setRowIndex(-1);
            this.rowIndex = -1;
        }else{
            super.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
            this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
        }

        if (getResults() == null) {
            return;
        }

        DataModelListener[] listeners = getDataModelListeners();
        if (listeners != null && oldIndex != this.rowIndex) {
            Object rowData = null;
            if (isRowAvailable()) {
                rowData = getRowData();
            }

            DataModelEvent dataModelEvent = new DataModelEvent(this, rowIndex, rowData);
            for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
                listeners[i].rowSelected(dataModelEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T getRowData() {
        return getResults().get(this.rowIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRowAvailable() {
        if(getResults() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < getResults().size();
    }

    /**
     * The complete list of results
     * @return
     */
    public abstract List<T> getResults();

}
```

The implementor needs to implement the getResults() method that provides the complete list of results.